# Audio Recording get file size

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioRecorder to record something in my iOS app, and I wanted to get the file size of the recording in bytes. Is there a way I can do that?

This is my code for setting up the recorder:

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
```

This is where I'm trying to get the file size:

```
- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    // Convert to NSData
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:recorder.url];
    // Convert to NSString
    NSString* dataAsString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
NSLog(@"Size: %@", dataAsString);
}
```

The NSLog doesn't return anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, you can get the file size by doing this:

```
unsigned long long size = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[recorder.url path] error:nil].fileSize;
```

and then convert it into a string by doing:

```
NSLog(@"This is the file size of the recording in bytes: %llu", size);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**, I just added this to the end of my audioRecorderDidFinishRecording delegate func:

```
    guard let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path) else {
        print("::: NO FILE SIZE!")
        return
    }

    if let fileSize = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as? Double {
        let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
        bcf.countStyle = .file
        let fileSize64 = Int64(fileSize)

        // BYTES:
        print("There were \(fileSize) bytes")

        // KILOBYTES:
        bcf.allowedUnits = [.useKB]
        let kbSizeString = bcf.string(fromByteCount: fileSize64)
        print("::: FILE SIZE: " + kbSizeString)

        // MEGABYTES:
        bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB]
        let mbSizeString = bcf.string(fromByteCount: fileSize64)
        print("::: FILE SIZE: " + mbSizeString)
    }
```